# Order of execution - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, execution

I have tried to debug the next program to understand the execution order, however I'm still confused about the execution order

```
fun foo(): String{
    println("Calculating foo...")
    return "foo"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("First ${foo()}, Second ${foo()}!")
}
// Result:
//
// Calculating foo...
// Calculating foo...
// First foo, Second foo!

// I though the execution would show something like this:
//
// First Calculating foo...foo,
// Second Calculating foo...foo!
```

Isn't **main** the initial function to be executed?
If it is, then **println** would be the 1st sentence, as such (for me) the execution would start from left to right (am I correct?), so... if it is the first word to be displayed would be First ,then it would be called the **foo()** function and this would return **"foo"**, that would be extrapolated to string again => $**{}**  ... am I right ?
If not, what I'm misunderstanding ?

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about it like this

1. Execute main() function.
2. Evaluate argument to println() function.

   - `"First ${foo()}, Second ${foo()}!"` is using string interpolation, so we need to first interpolate the string.
3. Interpolate first `${foo()}`, by calling foo()
4. First foo() prints `"Calculating foo..."`
5. Interpolate second `${foo()}`, by calling foo()
6. First foo() prints `"Calculating foo..."`

   - Now we have the interpolated string `First foo, Second foo!`
7. Execute `println("First foo, Second foo!")`

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts here :

1. The string interpolation will take the output of your function to build the output text. The println call in foo() is a side-effect, not included in return value. So, it won't be added to generated string.
2. println in main function will receive the result of String interpolation. Text is interpreted fully before being passed to println. That's why you see the output as is : to create the final text, kt will execute each string expression first, then builing the entire string to display, and finally pass the ready text to println function.

Code execution order is not strongly bound to the natural reading order. There is operator priority concept, also when executing a function, all its arguments must be evaluated before being passed to it (except for closures/lambda, but that's a more complicated subject). And there'smuch more rules. I can only encourage you to take a general programming courses to discover all these, because there's much to say, it would be tough to include all in a single SO answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it helped me as well to understand that code execution is no strongly bound to execution of a function.

Answer (score 0):

[Kotlin's String templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates) are resolved statically, and are converted to respective variable/function calls in concatenation with Strings.

A literal like `"test ${foo()} test2"` will be compiled as `"test " + foo() + "test2"` in the JVM bytecode.

---

Basically, your function call,

```kotlin
println("First ${foo()}, Second ${foo()}!")
```

is chopped down like:

```kotlin
println("First " + foo() + ", Second " + foo() + "!")
```

This will execute as follows:

```kotlin
println(  "First ".plus(foo()).plus(", Second ").plus(foo()).plus("!")  )
```

So first of all both the `foo` calls have been made after concatenation of all the Strings likewise in the above manner, final String is sent as an argument to the `println()`